# Launching an alarm without having browser launched with ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

first sorry for my English. 
I am creating a simple alarm website using asp.net. the alarm is set and than windows media player must run at a specific time and play a song. 
After running the website by clicking on the "run" button in visual studio 2015 and setting the time at the desired one, the app is launched and the task is done as expected.
If i want that task to be accomplished after launching the website to set the alarm but than clothing the browser (At the specific time with no webpage running the alarm is not launched). Is it possible to do it and if yes, please tell how to do it.

Comment: Is this for your own amusement or something intended to be used by others? Be aware that things are *very different* when the website and a desktop session are both on the same machine running under the same user account. Launching other applications is possible here, but not when the website is running on a separate server.

Comment: for my own, the website will be running just on the local server